# PHP Function: Not able to pass string values in Javascript Onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am facing a problem. I am using visual composer shortcode in my WP template and its working well, but now I have added an onClick button to pass some parameter.

When I pass the number its works but when I pass the string it's not working.

```
function my_functions($atts, $content = null){

        $title = 'Test & Title';
        $id = '123456'
        $envy_html_template =' 
                <button id="btnAdd" 
                    class="add-to-cart sc-add-to-cart"
                    onclick="addToCart('.$title.','.$id.' )" 
                >Test
                </button>';
        wp_reset_query();


    return $envy_html_template;
}
add_shortcode('my_template', 'my_functions');
```

Comment: Wrap your text in __quotes__.

Comment: I am wrapped and it works, but how to wrap this `$title =  "'get_the_title($idd)'";`

Comment: @Kane `$title = "'" .get_the_title($idd). "'"`;

Comment: @catcon Thanks. It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass string parameter like this

```
 onclick="addToCart(\'.$title.'\' , \'.$id.'\')
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_functions($atts, $content = null){

        $title = 'Test & Title';
        $id = '123456'
        $envy_html_template =' 
                <button id="btnAdd" 
                    class="add-to-cart sc-add-to-cart"
                    onclick="addToCart(\"'.$title.'\",\"'.$id.'\" )" 
                >Test
                </button>';
        wp_reset_query();


    return $envy_html_template;
}
add_shortcode('my_template', 'my_functions');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_functions($atts, $content = null){

        $title = 'Test & Title';
        $id = '123456'
        $envy_html_template =' 
                <button id="btnAdd" 
                    class="add-to-cart sc-add-to-cart"
                    onclick="addToCart(\''.$title.'\',\''.$id.'\' )" 
                >Test
                </button>';
        wp_reset_query();


    return $envy_html_template;
}
add_shortcode('my_template', 'my_functions');
```

Or simple do this:

```
function my_functions($atts, $content = null){

        $title = 'Test & Title';
        $id = '123456'
        $addtoCart = "addToCart('".$title."','".$id."')";
        $envy_html_template =' 
                <button id="btnAdd" 
                    class="add-to-cart sc-add-to-cart"
                    onclick="'.$addtoCart.'" 
                >Test
                </button>';
        wp_reset_query();


    return $envy_html_template;
}
add_shortcode('my_template', 'my_functions');
```